# PHP mail script not sending mails

Tags: php, sendmail, contacts, contact-form

I found a PHP script online that isn't working for me while it's nearly identical to others that do work. I just can't seem to get it fixed, here's the one that does work: http://pastebin.com/L1YQ20qf

Also I censored the email and tested it on a PHP supporting webhost, so that can't be the issue. Anyone?

```
    <?php
if($_POST)
{
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    }

    $to_Email       = "censored@myemail.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Contactformulier'; //Subject line for emails

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        die();
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["userPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Naam te kort.');
        exit();
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Controleer email adres.');
        exit();
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Alleen nummers als telefoonnummer.');
        exit();
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Bericht te kort.');
        exit();
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Kon het bericht niet verzenden, onze excuses!');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo 'Bericht verzonden!';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: We're almost at 15,000 php mail questions! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+mail+is%3Aquestion

Comment: There is an aching need for a step-by-step tutorial to debugging PHP email problems, which 90% of the time seem to be hosting or ISP problems.

Comment: I'm sorry.. But as I'm not a PHP debug guru this can be quite hard..

Comment: @luikstruik is the mail() function returning false? Or are you not receiving the email? You should really switch over to using PHPMailer or similar!

Comment: `@$sentMail = mail()` doesn't look like valid PHP to me.. Shouldn't that be `$sentMail = @mail()` ?

Comment: Change all your `"rn"` to `"\r\n"` Using `"rn"` is invalid. @luikstruik

Comment: Thank you guys, fixed it by doing this: http://pastebin.com/zAJWgsqR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOU SHOULD NOT BE USING THE MAIL() FUNCTION**

It is very hard to comply with email format RFCs manually using mail(). Instead, update your code to use PHPMailer or a similar library.

Your additional headers variable is incorrect - you must have a `Content-type` and `MIME-Version` header:

```
//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = "From: $user_Email\n" .
"Reply-To: $user_Email\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick although your code formatting is broken in the code above. This did the trick: http://pastebin.com/zAJWgsqR

Comment: By the way what exactly is the difference between X-Mailer and PHPMailer?

Comment: X-Mailer is just an email header to indicate what program sent the email. PHPMailer is a PHP library written to help people send emails using PHP successfully.

Comment: What was wrong with my formatting?

Comment: Might look into this PHPMailer then, sounds nice! Your formatting exists of 5 strings without variables: "Reply-To: $user_Email\n" should be: 'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n"

Comment: @luikstruik if you have a variable inside a double-quoted string, then the value of that variable is included in the string: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: Ah alright, never knew that.. my bad! :) Same goes for single-quoted strings?

Comment: No, single-quoted strings don't have that behaviour. Worth having a look through the manual from time to time :) Any chance you could flag this answer as correct?

Comment: Will do, thanks again! Flagged as correct, cheers!